# MS SQL Server Birt Data Source

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, birt

I have a huge problem right now:
I want to add a Birt Data Source and I get an error when testing the connection. 
My connection string is: `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;`
I have enabled tcp/ip and created the user with following script:

```
create login birt_jdbc with password = 'passwordhere,
default_database = SMaRT,
check_expiration = off,
check_policy = off;
go
create user birt_jdbc for login birt_jdbc;
go
use master;
go
grant connect SQL
    to birt_jdbc;`
```

I also granted him rights to read from Tables.
I really hope you can help me, because I can't find a solution anywhere, but I really need this to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried literally everything I could find and also asked a few friends, including a database engineer, for help and no one could fix it.

My solution is to use **jtds** instead of the microsoft driver.

Hope I can help someone struggling with a similar setup!

Answer (score 0):

try to complete the connection string as this
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=birt_jdbc;password=passwordhere;